# Xamarin/Android and the dread Bluetooth LE error 133 (GATT_ERROR)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth

I'm trying to write a cross-platform Xamarin Forms application (in C#) to talk to Bluetooth LE devices.  I've downloaded a few packages (Plugin.BLE and Acr.Ble) and neither one works (they both scan but won't connect), so I thought I would try using the Android API directly to see if that would help me understand what's failing.   BTW, I'm running on a Nexus 7 tablet running Android version 6.0.1.

I'm successfully scanning for devices:

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService (Android.Content.Context.BluetoothService);
m_adapter = bluetoothManager.Adapter;
if ((m_adapter == null) || (!m_adapter.IsEnabled))
    return false;
m_scanCallback = new BlueCallback (this);
m_adapter.BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan (m_scanCallback);
```

and I see the device I want to talk to (in this case, a TI development board MSP-EXP430F5438 in Server mode, running their SPPLE demo application).  So I stop the scan:

```
m_adapter.BluetoothLeScanner.StopScan (m_scanCallback);
```

and then I connect to the desired device:

```
m_gattCallback = new BlueGattCallback ();
m_gatt = m_selectedDevice.ConnectGatt (Forms.Context, false, m_gattCallback);
```

and I pretty much immediately get a call back saying the connection failed:

```
BlueGattCallback.OnConnectionStateChange(gatt, status=133, newState=Disconnected)
```

I read [this Google bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69834) so in my callback I tried calling Connect() directly in my callback:

```
if ( ((int)status == 133) && (numRetries < 10) )
{
    numRetries++;
    bool connect = gatt.Connect ();
    Debug.WriteLine ("   gatt.Connect() returned " + connect);
}
```

This code fails with error 133 repeatedly and quite quickly (all 10 retries take about 3 seconds).

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: p.s. I'm not doing any threading so as far as I know, all this is happening in the main UI Thread.

Comment: p.p.s. I just checked, and my callback is happening in a thread, so I changed the code to use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() to call gatt.Connect() in my main UI thread and it doesn't help.         p.p.p.s. The Acr.Ble plugin works correctly on iOS so this is an Android-only problem.

Comment: p.p.p.p.s. We tried this on a Note 4 and a G4 as well, with the exact same results.

Comment: I have the same problem..

Comment: i am facing the same problem :-( did you found any solution?

Comment: We had some success putting a 2-second delay between the StopScan() and the ConnectGatt().  It also seemed to help to make sure we shut down the BLE connection cleanly instead of just killing the app in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

As this is dependant on the BLE stack which each vendor develops,
the error generally occurs on Samsung devices more than any other type, Android 6 being the most unstable.

So for anyone running into the 133 error and having many sleepless nights because of it. I would recommend using the [Sweetblue](https://github.com/iDevicesInc/SweetBlue)
wrapper, you will however need to wrap the library yourself for use in C#.
It abstracts many of the unstable parts of BLE and provides good retry mechanisms as well as graceful degradation in certain cases.

But in the end this does not solve all problems and you will need to handle some of the instability yourself.